# How can I run my python script on AWS lambda 24/7

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Is it possible to run my run my python script on AWS lambda 24/7 without the 5mins limit?

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to do this? Normally a Lambda function is triggered by an external event (eg object uploaded to S3, message received in SNS). What is your Python function doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create one Lambda that runs every 5 minutes and creates a new Lambda that runs your code. You would just have to have your program work in such a way that it can be interrupted every 5 minutes.

However, this is not really the point of Lambda. You might consider using a virtual machine on [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) or an [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) instance, which is also serverless but designed to run persistent applications.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the purpose of AWS Lambda. If you want to run something 24/7, you'll be better off using an ec2 instance.